# Configuring permissions to folder in ubuntu in order to prevent user's from removing files of others

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a folder owned by a group named "wheel".

The 'ls' command details for that folder is:

```
drwxrws--- 2 tps wheel 4096 may 8 08:10 tsreports
```

(tps = a user, owner of the file, wheel = the group, tsreports = name of the folder)

---

I need to configure the folder permissions in such way that files written into it are still owned by the wheel group, but so that one member of wheel cannot delete another member's files.

I think I already managed the part where newly created files in the folder will be automatically owned by the 'wheel' group
(I used `chmod g+s tpsreports` in order to do that)
but I'm not sure how I can prevent one member of 'wheel' from deleting another's file.

I could use some help, Thanks.

Comment: This isn't the answer you're looking for, but it may not be entirely safe to allow multiple users to mix and mingle in a `setgid` directory.  For example, there's nothing preventing someone from creating a symlink in this directory that targets a file within a user's home directory.  Attempts to edit such symlinks could result in corruption of the target user's important configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the internet, I found [this URL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/secfile-60/index.html), mentioning a "sticky bit", which might solve your problem.